# Difference between spec and test folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have a concept problem, I am working on a rails project & as per my knowledge both the test & spec are used for tests. Where test refers to unit testing & spec refers to integration testing. But I want to have to have full idea about those two folders & if they both refers to test then what is the major difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails default testing framework gives you test folder for you [rails default testing framework](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), if you want to use RSpec testing framework, which gives you folder called 'spec' [RSPEC](http://rspec.info/), it is your wish to select which option, RSPEC specs are more readable, people use both ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Monoj, can you please tell me which suits best in which condition or what are the advantages of using rspec.

Comment: I will suggest you to select RSpec , it gives better readability , methods etc which gives you felling you like you are writing plain english.